# bind this - call delete item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I would like to ask more experienced coleagues for help in understanding below piece of code and make it working in my App.

The general goal is to invoke an REDUX action from my button, which will delete an item from a database.

Here is a piece of code that works for me:

```
  <MenuItem onClick={this.props.deleteTrip.bind(this, trip.id)}>
      deleteTrip
  </MenuItem>
```

and this code is a part of this file:

```
class Trips extends Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,
    dialogOpen: false
  };

  //integracja z reduxem
  static propTypes = {
    trips: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  //

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      anchorEl: null
    });
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({
      anchorEl: event.currentTarget
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { label, status, trips } = this.props;
    const { anchorEl, dialogOpen } = this.state;
    const TripsFiltered = [];

      return (
        <Fragment>
          <List>
              <ListItemLink>
                <ListItemAvatar>
                  <Avatar>
                    <WorkIcon />
                  </Avatar>
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <ListItemText
                  primary={trip.remarks}
                  secondary={
                    trip.startDate + "-" + trip.endDate + ", " + trip.place
                  }
                />
                <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  <IconButton
                    edge="end"
                    aria-label="more"
                    aria-controls="simple-menu"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                  >
                    <MoreIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                  <Menu
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    keepMounted
                    open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                  >
                    <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>editTrip</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem
                      onClick={this.props.deleteTrip.bind(this, trip.id)}>
                      deleteTrip
                    </MenuItem>
                  </Menu>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
              </ListItemLink>
          </List>
        </Fragment>
      );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  trips: state.tripsReducer.trips
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { deleteTrip }
)(Trips);
```

But the case for me is that before deleting a Trip from database I want to show to the user a warning message so I modified the code like that:

```
class Trips extends Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,
    dialogOpen: false
  };

  //integracja z reduxem
  static propTypes = {
    trips: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  //
  handleOpenWarning = () => {
    this.setState({
      dialogOpen: true
    });
  };

  handleCloseWarning = () => {
    this.setState({
      dialogOpen: false
    });
  };

  handleDeleteTrip = () => {
    this.setState({
      dialogOpen: false
    });
    this.props.deleteTrip.bind(this, trip.id);
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      anchorEl: null
    });
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({
      anchorEl: event.currentTarget
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { label, status, trips } = this.props;
    const { anchorEl, dialogOpen } = this.state;
    const TripsFiltered = [];

    return (
        <Fragment>
          <List>
             <ListItemLink>
                <ListItemAvatar>
                  <Avatar>
                    <WorkIcon />
                  </Avatar>
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <ListItemText
                  primary={trip.remarks}
                  secondary={
                    trip.startDate + "-" + trip.endDate + ", " + trip.place
                  }
                />
                <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                  <IconButton
                    edge="end"
                    aria-label="more"
                    aria-controls="simple-menu"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    onClick={this.handleClick}
                  >
                    <MoreIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                  <Menu
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    keepMounted
                    open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                  >
                    <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>editTrip</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem
                      onClick={this.handleOpenWarning}
                    >
                      deleteTrip
                    </MenuItem>
                  </Menu>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
              </ListItemLink>
          </List>
          <Dialog
            open={dialogOpen}
            onClose={this.handleCloseWarning}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
          >
            <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
              {"Selected Trip will be deleted."}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={this.handleCloseWarning} color="primary">
                Cancel
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={this.handleDeleteTrip} color="primary" autoFocus>
                Delete
              </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </Dialog>
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  trips: state.tripsReducer.trips
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { deleteTrip }
)(Trips);
```

So after that modification I call {this.props.deleteTrip.bind(this, trip.id)} from handleDeleteTrip() function instead from onClick event directly. But when I do that I got:

```
./src/Trips/Trips.js
  Line 57:  'trip' is not defined  no-undef
```

In fact I dont understand to much this piece of code
{this.props.deleteTrip.bind(this, trip.id)}, so Im not sure how to properly use it in my arrow function to get this working.

Comment: Read this article about props binding https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/   it will help you better understand the behavior of the props

Answer (score 1):

in `handleDeleteTrip()`. there is no definition of the `trip`

```
  handleDeleteTrip = () => {
    this.setState({
      dialogOpen: false
    });
    this.props.deleteTrip.bind(this, trip.id);
  };
```

so you should pass the trip to the argument.
like this

```
  handleDeleteTrip = (trip) => {
    this.setState({
      dialogOpen: false
    });
    this.props.deleteTrip.bind(this, trip.id);
  };
...
              <Button onClick={(e) => this.handleDeleteTrip(trip)} color="primary" autoFocus>
                Delete
              </Button>
```

Comment: It seems it still doesn't work but right now i got: ./src/Trips/Trips.js
  Line 145:  'trip' is not defined  no-undef, which points that "trip" is not defined inside button